# reduce code duplication in c++

Tags: c++, refactoring

Can I reduce the following code to one function? the most part of them are the same. Thanks

```
void info(StreamLog &streamLog)
{
    streamLog.ss << "info:";
    streamLog.mFilter->setLogLevel("info");
}
void debug(StreamLog &streamLog)
{
    streamLog.ss << "debug:";
    streamLog.mFilter->setLogLevel("debug");
}
void warning(StreamLog &streamLog)
{
    streamLog.ss << "warning:";
    streamLog.mFilter->setLogLevel("warning");
}
void error(StreamLog &streamLog)
{
    streamLog.ss << "error:";
    streamLog.mFilter->setLogLevel("error");
}
void critical(StreamLog &streamLog)
{
    streamLog.ss << "critical:";
    streamLog.mFilter->setLogLevel("critical");
}
```

if you need more info,let me know

1st edited:
sorry !  I didnt explain my situation clearly.   I use those function as manipulator. therefore, i can do

clog << info << ...

clog << warning<<...

I dont want to use

clog << log(info) <<...

any better way? thanks

Answer (score 10):

```
void log(StreamLog &streamLog, const string& level)
{
    streamLog.ss << level << ":";
    streamLog.mFilter->setLogLevel(level);
}
```

Always try to see the common operation and abstract it in a different function.

Answer (score 2):

I'm with @Rémi Benoit, though to provide you with an alternative, you can use an `enum` and a map:

```
enum log_level {
   info, debug, warning, error, critical
}

void log(StreamLog& streamLog, log_level level) {
   static const std::map<log_level, std::string> levels = {
       { info, "info" }, { debug, "debug" }, { warning, "warning" },
       { error, "error" }, { critical, "critical" }
   };

   auto iter = levels.find(level);
   if(iter == levels.end()) return;

   streamLog.ss << iter->second;
   streamLog.mFilter->setLogLevel(iter->second);
}
```

The benefit of this is that your log level is limited only to what is in the `enum` (and the map), though if you do not require this constraint, it is better to use @Rémi's solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative to Mark's & Rémi's solutions using templates. This solution could be useful in areas where high performance is critical. The templates let the compiler bake in a lot of information into each templated function already so there should be a smaller run time cost especially when compared to the map lookup method.

Additionally this will constrain the values for the log_level being used at compile time rather than at run time.

```
enum class log_level { info, debug, warning, error, critical };
template<log_level> struct log_helper{ static const char* const text; };

template<> const char* const log_helper<log_level::info>::text = "info";
template<> const char* const log_helper<log_level::debug>::text = "debug";
template<> const char* const log_helper<log_level::warning>::text = "warning";
template<> const char* const log_helper<log_level::error>::text = "error";
template<> const char* const log_helper<log_level::critical>::text = "critical";

template<log_level level> void set_log_level(StreamLog& streamLog)
{
    streamLog.ss<< log_helper<level>::text << ":";
    streamLog.mFilter->setLogLevel(log_helper<level>::text);
}
```